# Can Sublime Text 3 support project-specific snippets?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm working on a front-end web app that has a bunch of reused components, and I would like to make snippets in order to decrease hand-typed code. The problem is that I don't want those snippets to appear in other projects, with different components.

I've set up my folder to be a sublime project (having the `*.sublime-project` file in the root)

Is there any straightforward way to do this?

Comment: There was a feature request some time ago:  
https://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/23900-project-based-snippets/

Comment: Not very straightforward, but you could make a plugin which has a `Project Snippets` sub-directory that users populate with `ProjectName/SnippetName.sublime-snippet`.  When they run the command, ST3 shows a searchable QuickPanel listing all found snippets for the current project, end executes them when the user presses enter.

Answer (score 0):

As of writing, `ST build 3120`, there is no way to do this.

A quick workaround: (requires [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io))

Put the snippets inside a folder inside the packages directory.

`Menu > Preferences > Browse Packages...`.

This folder/package can then be enabled/disabled very quickly via the Command Palette, `Ctrl+shift+P` then type to find the enable/disable command, using Package Control.